# Check if an array is empty in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

How can I check if an array is empty with a IF statment?

I have this array 'acessos' that's empty

```
...
constructor(props){
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      acessos:[]
    };
  }
...
```

Then I'm trying to check if 'acessos' is empty and if it is I push some data in it. I've tried with null but with no results, so how can I check if is empty?

```
...
if(this.state.acessos === null){
      this.state.acessos.push({'uuid': beacons.uuid, 'date':date});
      this.setState({acessos: this.state.acessos});
} else {
...
```

Comment: Do: `if(!this.state.acessos.length) { ... }`

Comment: @Proz1g it should probably be pointed out that you should not change items in state directly but always use `setState` instead. [The documentation states](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/react-component.html#state) *"Never mutate this.state directly, as calling setState() afterwards may replace the mutation you made. Treat this.state as if it were immutable."* Meaning you should avoid doing things like `this.state.acessos.push(...);` Technically what you're doing there works fine because you are using `setState` after, but I wanted to point that out for anyone else happening across this.

Comment: @jasonmerino so how can I push an element into the array without using this.state.push?

Comment: @Proz1g `this.setState({ acessos: [...this.state.acessos, { uuid: ... }] })` would accomplish this. But as I mentioned, what you have works because you are calling `this.setState` after mutating it. I just wanted to make sure it was clear that mutating items in the state directly and not calling `this.setState` after would be problematic.

Comment: Ah ok! Thank you very much! ;)

Answer (score 52):

I agree to Julien. Also you don't have to compare it to null. You can write it like

```
this.state.acessos && this.state.acessos.length > 0
```

Answer (score 31):

Just check if your array exists and has a length:

```js
if (this.state.products && this.state.products.length) {
     //your code here
}
```

No need to check `this.state.products.length > 0`. 
`0` is falsy anyway, a small performance improvement.

Answer (score 6):

If checking the array length as part of conditional rendering in React JSX, remember that if condition is falsy at length check, it will render a 0 as in the following example:

```
{myArray && myArray.length && (
      <div className="myclass">
        Hello
      </div>
    )}
```

This is not what we want most of the time. Instead you can modify the JSX as follows:

```
{myArray && myArray.length? (
      <div className="myclass">
        Hello
      </div>
    ):""}
```

Answer (score 5):

You need not even check for the length since ECMAScript 5.1
You can simply write the same condition as follows.

```
this.state.acessos && this.state.acessos.length
```

By default `this.state.acessos.length` checks if the length is NOT undefined or null or zero.

Answer (score 0):

instead of`null` its better to replace `""` like this `if ( this.state.acessos == ""){}`

Comment: Add some comments to your code explaining the why?

Comment: `acessos` is not a string, so why would you compare it to a string? You must provide an informed solution, and not simply an opinion such as "I think that..., it's better to...". I suggest you edit this answer to explain the *why*, or remove it.

Answer (score 0):

```
 Array?console.log('array is empty'):console.log('array have values')
```

or

```
if (Array){
   console.log('array is empty')
else{
   console.log('array have values')
}
```